# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage override IsPresent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to set my MasterDetailPage to always display the MasterPage on tablet layout:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
        {
            this.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        }
        else
        {
            this.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Split;
        }
    }
```

However, the hamburger icon is still displayed and when clicking on it I get an error saying `Can't change IsPresented when setting Split`. How do I override the `IsPresented` property? I was trying to bind a method to the `IsPresentedChanged`, but the event is fired only after the `IsPresented` value is changed, not before - thus I still get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

i can't make a comment, so have had to put this as an answer.

Can you set IsPresented = true, before you set the behaviour to split?

As that should make the master page visible, and not the hamburger icon.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The hamburger icon is still displayed.